# Gradetable for each question?

Tags: exam

We are writing an exam of 5 problems. Each problem should be on its own page and will be corrected by each teacher involved in this exam. To simplify the process I would like to display a gradetable before each problem.

It is possible with `exam` to display *sub-gradetable* that only display the next question points?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\title{Exam}
\author{John Doe}    
\begin{coverpages}
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}        
    % Gradetable for all questions
    \begin{center}
        \gradetable
    \end{center}
\end{coverpages}

\begin{questions}

% Gradetable for this question only
\question[10] What is the answer to everything?
\begin{solutionordottedlines}[1cm]
42
\end{solutionordottedlines}    
\newpage
% Gradetable for this question only
\question[10] Do you know foo
\begin{solutionordottedlines}[1cm]
yes
\end{solutionordottedlines}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

[image: e]

[image: f]

> You can define a grading range by choosing a name with which to label
> the range, e.g., “myrange”, and then putting the command
> `\begingradingrange{myrange}` at the start of the range and the
> command `\endgradingrange{myrange}`  at the end of the range.
>
> `\partialgradetable{myrange}[v][questions]` would create a vertically
> grading oriented table indexed by the questions in the range.

(See  user’s guide for version 2.7 of the exam document class, page #90)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}
    \title{Exam}
    \author{John Doe}    
    \begin{coverpages}
        \maketitle
        \thispagestyle{empty}        
        % Gradetable for all questions
        \begin{center}
            \gradetable
        \end{center}
    \end{coverpages}
    
    \partialgradetable{questioni}[v][questions] \vspace*{10ex}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \begin{questions}   
    % Gradetable for this question only
    \begingradingrange{questioni} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
        \question[10] What is the answer to everything?
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1cm]
        42
        \end{solutionordottedlines} 
    \endgradingrange{questioni}    % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
        
    \newpage
    
    \partialgradetable{questionii}[v][questions]  \vspace*{10ex}
        
    % Gradetable for this question only
    \begingradingrange{questionii}
        \question[10] Do you know foo
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1cm]
        yes
        \end{solutionordottedlines}
    \endgradingrange{questionii}
    
    \newpage
    \partialgradetable{questioniii}[v][questions] \vspace*{10ex}    
        
    % Gradetable for this question only
    \begingradingrange{questioniii}     
        \question[10] Do you know foo
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1cm]
        yes
        \end{solutionordottedlines}
        
        \question[10] Do you know bar
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1cm]
        yes
        \end{solutionordottedlines}
        
        \question[10] Do you know baz
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1cm]
        no
        \end{solutionordottedlines} 
    
    \endgradingrange{questioniii}
    
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```